# spatial econometrics: homogeneity of indirect effects across variables

Tags: regression, econometrics, spatial

Take the model $y=\beta X + \rho Wy +\epsilon$

where X contains the dependent variables and W is the weighting matrix. We have that:

$y = (I-\rho W)^{-1}I\beta X = aX$

We can compute the average indirect effect as the average total effect minus the average direct effect.

The average direct effect would be the average of the diagonal elements of $a$ and the average total effect would be the average of the sum of the rows of $a$.

My issue is that, given the constancy of $a$ and its non-dependence on $X$, we are de facto imposing that the proportion of average indirect effects to average direct effects associated with each variable in $X$ is exactly the same, which sounds notably non-intuitive.

Am I am missing something here (wrong interpretation) or is there a way around this?

Second question related to this model:

While we can compute average indirect effects as described above, we can also isolate the effects associated with specific observations by retrieving the specific elements of interest in matrix $a$. Would such an exercise be correct and meaningful?